# Convert an object stored in React State to an array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-state

I'm trying to use an array which was received from a server (in response after my GET request). I successfully receive it and store it in a dbdata.purchases State variable. console.log prints it to me as an array, but its tipe is 'object'.

> dbdata.purchases= (2) [1, 2]
> 0: 1

> 1: 2

> length: 2

> **proto**: Array(0)

As a result, I cannot access its [i] element. The 'content' variable in the fucntion get_rewards equals '12'.

Question: what should I do to access each element of dbdata.purchases array?

I tried to convert this variable into array using Array.from() and Object.values but both of these attmpts did not success.
Here is the code:

```
    const Offers = () => {
    const [dbdata, setdbdata] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        let login = window.localStorage.getItem('rr_login');
        const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/get_rewards?login=' + login;
        fetch(apiUrl)
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => setdbdata(data));           
    }, [])

    function get_rewards () {
        let content =[];
        console.log('dbdata.purchases=',dbdata.purchases);
        for (var i=0; i<1;i++)  // should be 'for (var i=0; i<lenght(dbdata.purchases);i++)' but it doesn't work since dbdata.purchases is not considered an array
        {
            content.push(dbdata.purchases); // should be content.push(dbdata.purchases[i]);
        }
        return content;    
    }    
    return (
        <div>
            <h5 className="mb-3">Your purchases</h5>
            <CardDeck>
                {get_rewards()}
            </CardDeck>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: should you put data that you receive from the server?

Comment: put console.log(data) before setdbdata(data) and share the log with us

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you need to set your state dbdata to an array:

```
const [dbdata, setdbdata] = useState([]);
```

Then when you have made the request and the state is set, you can access each element in the state array through indexing: `dbdata[0]` gets the first element in the array.

So your loop would be

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
content.push(dbdata[i]);
}
```

Comment: An improved implementation of the loop would be dbdata.purchases.map((purchase) => content.push(purchase));